# Implenting ActiveRecord with inheritance?

Tags: .net, design-patterns, object-oriented

I recently converted an old application that was using XML files as the data store to use SQL instead. To avoid a lot of changes I basically created ActiveRecord style classes that inherited from the original business objects.

For example

```
SomeClassRecord :SomeClass
//ID Property
//Save method
```

I then used this new class in place of the other one, because of polymorphism I didn't need to change any methods that took SomeClass as a parameter.

Would this be considered 'Bad'? What would be a better alternative?

Comment: What do you mean by "bad?"  Does it meet your customer's requirements for functionality and maintainability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not say this is a 'Bad' thing to do.  But there are alternatives with their own trade-offs.

Assuming that the way the original classes were used was the ActiveRecord pattern, here are some alternatives.

1. Modify each business object's `Save()` method to delegate the saving work to a class responsible for dealing with storage, whether it's XML or SQL.  Instead of decorating each class, you delegate the saving to a single interface, say, `IDataStore`.  For example:

   ```
   public class SomeClass {
       IDataStore dataStore; // how this gets set can vary also
       public void Save() {
           dataStore.Save(this);
       }
   }
   ```

   Now the change is in the implementation of `IDataStore`.
2. Continue using your business objects in the business layer, but when doing data access, map your business objects to data access objects, and use the [Repository](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) pattern.  For example:

   ```
   public class SomeBusinessProcess {
     public void DoSomeWork(SomeClass someClass) {
       // ... do some work on someClass ...

       // now save
       SomeClassDAO someClassDao = AutoMapper.Map<SomeClass, SomeClassDAO>(); // can use AutoMapper, for example
       repository.Save(someClassDao);
     }
   ```

You really can take it as far as you want, based on what your needs are.

Answer (score 1):

In no way is this is not a 'bad' thing to do. What you did is akin to the decorator pattern.  http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternDecorator.aspx

In fact I suggest that you do read up on the decorator pattern as its a useful tool to have in your design arsenal.